# RxJS buffer until changed

Tags: rxjs

Is there a nice way of creating a "buffer until changed" function? Basically, I have a sorted observable like `[1,1,1,2,2,2,4,5,5]` and I want to create an observable of observables (or any collection, really) like [`[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [4], [5,5]]`.

`groupBy` could theoretically work in this case, but it causes huge memory consumption in my application due to it not closing the group observables immediately, which is unnecessary since I know the original observable is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that also works with immediate Observables (rxjs 5) :

```
source
  .concat(Observable.of('~'))
  .scan(({ buffer }, item) => buffer.length === 0 || buffer.includes(item) ? 
        ({ buffer: [...buffer, item] }) : 
        ({ buffer: [item], output: buffer }), { buffer: [] })
  .pluck('output')
  .filter(x => x);
```

http://jsbin.com/ruyozinali/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I am looking for a similar one in RxJava.  Do you have an RxJava version of the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `bufferWhen` combined with `distinctUntilChanged`. Something like this:

```
source.bufferWhen(() => source.distinctUntilChanged())
```

Comment: This causes a stack overflow when source is a `Observable.of([1,1,2, etc.])`. I also tried `source.buffer(source.distinctUntilChanged())`, but this does not work either as it relies on timing. It might work when the items are added over an interval, but I'd rather not depend on timing (don't want race conditions).

Comment: Maybe the stack overflow is caused by the fact that the observable is cold. You'd need to multicast the source maybe?